# Search button error

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have a search button to search the database by a name entered in a text box, this is working fine within visual studio but when trying to use this in the hosted version i get the following message:

Server Error in '/' Application.

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

the code for this button is:

```
    GridView2.Visible = True

    lblEnterName.Text = ""

    If txtLoanName.Text = "" Then

        lblEnterName.Text = "Please enter a Bandie's Name"

    Else



        Dim conn As SqlConnection = Nothing
        Try
            Dim connString As String = "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\BandDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
            conn = New SqlConnection(connString)

            Dim query As String = "SELECT [SongName], [PartLearnt], [Status] FROM [Learning] WHERE ([BandieName] LIKE '%' + @Name + '%') ORDER BY [SongName]"


            Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(query, conn)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtLoanName.Text)
            conn.Open()
            Dim dr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
            Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
            dt.Load(dr)
            GridView2.DataSource = dt
            GridView2.DataBind()

            lblSearchBandieName.Text = "Progress for " + txtLoanName.Text


        Finally
            conn.Close()
        End Try

    End If
```

I am unsure why this is bringing the error as didnt before, all i have done is changed the page the button is on.

Thanks

Comment: did you check the information in the connection string? probably not an sqlexpres on the hosted solution. Also you may want to have the connection info in the web.config

Comment: Of course, i completely forgot these use different ones! thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you check the information in the connection string? probably not an sqlexpres on the hosted solution. Also you may want to have the connection info in the web.config

Now as an answer....: -)